# UIPickerView with done button not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uibarbuttonitem, toolbar

Picker view with toolbar, created Done button on it.  On click Done button its not working.

The picker view scrolling upwards. on click Done button.

```
-(void)createPicker:(id)sender{

    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,0,0)];
    [pickerView setDataSource: self];
    [pickerView setDelegate: self];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [pickerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneTouched:)];
    [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil], doneButton, nil]];
    [pickerView addSubview:toolBar];
}
```

On click done button dismiss the pickerView

```
-(void)doneTouched:(id)sender{
     [pickerview removeFromSuperview];
 }
```

I have no clue what i did wrong here.  Can any one advice me how to invoke done button method which added on uipickerview toolbar button.

On clicking done picker view is scrolling up,  not invoking the method **doneTouched:**

@All
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Your picker view has no frame: CGRectMake(0,100,0,0)

Comment: I'm pointing that out because it could very well be the reason you're not able to interact with the toolbar since the toolbar isn't technically within the UIPickerView frame.

Comment: @LyndseyScott  I am unable to figure out.  What i did wrong.

Comment: Try setting UIPickerView to something like `pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,self.view.frame.size.width,44)];` (the same as the toolbar)

Comment: @LyndseyScott This is what i did it     pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height-200,self.view.frame.size.width,100)];   and  for toolbar     UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,42)];

Comment: So you changed this line? `pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,0,0)];` to what I just wrote?

Comment: @LyndseyScott  I changed that line!!!! its not yet working...:(

Comment: Oh, wait... What do you mean by "done button not working." Is `doneTouched:` being called? Have you used a breakpoint or log to check?

Comment: @ Yeap i did that! its not working. Need to invoke doneTouched: method on click done. that my problem here.

Answer (score 6):

I have resolved the issue which do not know is proper way to implement or not, but it work for me.
Below code for picker view with done button

```
-(void)createPickerView{

    pickerToolBarView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height/2, self.view.frame.size.width,400)];
    [pickerToolBarView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,pickerToolBarView.frame.size.width,42)];
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneTouched:)];
    [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil], doneButton, nil]];

    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,toolBar.frame.size.height,toolBar.frame.size.width,100)];
    [pickerView setDataSource: self];
    [pickerView setDelegate: self];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [pickerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [pickerToolBarView addSubview:toolBar];
    [pickerToolBarView addSubview:pickerView];
    [self.view addSubview:pickerToolBarView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:pickerToolBarView];
    [pickerToolBarView setHidden:YES];   
}

/* Done Touched */
- (void)doneTouched:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender{
    // hide the  view
    NSLog(@"Done Touched");
    [pickerToolBarView setHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding toolbar as subview do:

```
yourTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;
```

Comment: What if I don't have a textfield?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue.  My problem was I was not tying the picker to a text field directly, I was bringing up the picker from a button.  I also wanted a "Done" button to get rid of the picker when I was done.  The problem, I think, was that I was putting the toolbar as part of the picker view and for some reason I could not get the button to work.  What I did was make the toolbar a subview of the view and set its y value to the corner of the picker - 44.  This moved it to the top of the picker and allowed the button to work.
There are quite a few questions here about this very problem and none of them seemed to work for me.  I started with the example from Gabriel Theodoropoulos on his site: http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.com/2011/04/uipickerview-add-it-programmatically_04.html
and made a few changes.  Here is what I came up with and it seems to work for me:

In the .h file:

```
`   
    @interface Detail() <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *pickerData;
    @property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger pickerRowSelected;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *barButtonDone;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIToolbar *toolBar;
    @end

`
```

In the .m file:`

```
-(void)showPicker{
    // Calculate the screen's width.
    float screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    float pickerWidth = screenWidth * 3 / 4;

    // Calculate the starting x coordinate.
    float xPoint = screenWidth / 2 - pickerWidth / 2;

    // Init the picker view.
    picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];

    // Set the delegate and datasource. Don't expect picker view to work
    // correctly if you don't set it.
    [picker setDataSource: self];
    [picker setDelegate: self];

    // Set the picker's frame. We set the y coordinate to 50px.
    [picker setFrame: CGRectMake(xPoint, 150.0f, pickerWidth, 200.0f)];

    // Before we add the picker view to our view, let's do a couple more
    // things. First, let the selection indicator (that line inside the
    // picker view that highlights your selection) to be shown.
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

    // Allow us to pre-select the first option in the pickerView.
    [picker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

    [picker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

    toolBar= [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,150-44,pickerWidth,44)];

    barButtonDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(itemWasSelected:)];
    [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: barButtonDone, nil]];

    // OK, we are ready. Add the picker in our view.
    [self.view addSubview: picker];

    // Add the done button to the picker view
    [self.view addSubview:toolBar];
    [toolBar becomeFirstResponder];
}


// The number of columns of data
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

// The number of rows of data
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return pickerData.count;
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return pickerData[row];
}

// Catpure the picker view selection
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    // This method is triggered whenever the user makes a change to the picker selection.
    // The parameter named row and component represents what was selected.
    self.pickerRowSelected  = row;
}

-(IBAction)itemWasSelected:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"Picker selected = %@",[pickerData objectAtIndex: self.pickerRowSelected]);
    //NSLog(@"ID = %ld",(long)[self.thisData getIDForEntry:@"company" column:@"name" entry:[pickerData objectAtIndex: self.pickerRowSelected]]);
    [picker setHidden:YES];
    [toolBar setHidden:YES];

}


- (NSAttributedString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView attributedTitleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    NSAttributedString *attString =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[pickerData objectAtIndex:row] attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];

    return attString;
}

//bring up the size Picker
//This is tied to a button from IB and when pressed will bring up
//the picker.  The index returned is stored in self.pickerRowSelected 
- (IBAction)sizeButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    self.pickerData = [self.thisData getSizePickerData];
    [self showPicker];

}
```

`
I am sure there are better ways to accomplish this but this works for me and I am using it for now.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue.
The problem was that I added UIToolbar as subview to UIPickerView.

This is what I did to solve it.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var myPicker: UIPickerView!
    var myPickerToolBar: UIToolbar!

    func showPicker() {
         myPicker = UIPickerView()
         /*
         setup UIPickerView
         */
         view.addSubview(myPicker)

         myPickerToolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect())
         /*
         setup UIToolbar with barButtons, one of barButtons runs hidePicker()
         */
         view.addSubview(myPickerToolBar)
    }

    @objc func hidePicker() {
        myPicker.removeFromSuperview()
        myPickerToolBar.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```